# Why Is Firebase modular version 9 not generating unique id for its documents in Real time Database as Firestore does?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on firebase real-time database v9 but when I send data to the database the generated unique id for each document is not generated as it was in version 8 instead it maps the data in the name of collection hence I cant push another data. I have provided an image to show what is happening
[image]

```
    function writeUserData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    

    set(ref(realtime, "customers/"), {Name:cname,Contact: 
                contact,
                   Serial:serial,  Device: device, Served: 
               served, AmountC:amountc, 
                AmountP:amountp, Status:status }).then(() => {

                   toast.success("Data Saved Succefully");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
             setError(err.message);
      });
      
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `set()` method does not generate a random ID. It just adds the data at the path specified. You must use `push()` to generate a random ID:

```
push(ref(realtime, "customers/"), {...data}).then(() => {
  console.log("Data added")
})
```

Comment: You're the Best Man. It Worked .

Comment: Note that this is not a change in v9. In v8 and before too (in fact, all the way back to v0 of the SDK), the method to auto-generate a unique child ID for the data has been called `push`, while `set` replaces whatever exists in the path already.

Comment: I think I missed that. and when do you use the child method?

Comment: `child()` is just used to get a [DatabaseReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.databasereference). `ref()` also returns the same. So `child(ref(realtime), "customers")` is same as `ref(realtime, "customers")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro. fully understood

Comment: @Dharmaraj can You help with this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70576489/table-data-not-showing I am almost giving up on this project I don't Know if I am Missing something