# Table data Not Showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I managed to write data into a Firebase Realtime database and also retrieve them but when I try to map them into a table I get empty records but the index Number keeps updating showing that data is available but I cant see them in the table.

Image of my table and database

[image: My records Table]

In my realtime database, I have four existing documents in customer collection. This is my Useffect code that should render data whenever the page is active

```
 useEffect(() => {
            const readCustomerData= async()=> {
    
                await get(ref(realtime, "customers")).then( (snapshot) => {
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        console.log(snapshot.val());
                       setCustomers({...snapshot.val()});
    
                    }else 
    
                    {
                        setCustomers({});
                    }
                })
    
                return () => {
                    setCustomers({});
                };
    
            };
    
            readCustomerData();
        },[]);
```

And this my Mapping code of data to the table

```
 <tbody>

                 { Object.keys(customers).map((id,index) => {
                     return(

                        <tr key={id}>
                   
                        <th scope="row">{index+ 1}</th>


                        <td>{customers[id].cname}</td>
                        <td>{customers[id].contact}</td>
                        <td>{customers[id].serial}</td>
                        <th>{customers[id].device}</th>
                        <td>{customers[id].served}</td>
                        <td>{customers[id].amountc}</td>
                        <td>{customers[id].amountp}</td>
                        <td>{customers[id].status}</td>

                        <td className='p-2 d-flex justify-content-space-between'>
                            <Button  variant='danger'>Delete</Button>
                           
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                     )

                 })}

            </tbody>
```

The Json data

```
{


 "customers" : {
    "-MsVY4KWphiYjMtBVCU9" : {
      "AmountC" : "4500",
      "AmountP" : "2500",
      "Contact" : "+254704407239",
      "Device" : "Laptop having insufficient RAM",
      "Name" : "Maxwel",
      "Serial" : "GYYBUHNJIML85",
      "Served" : "Bonnie",
      "Status" : "BALANCE"
    },
    "-MsV_ZzmRQyGuOuCPP-b" : {
      "AmountC" : "5000",
      "AmountP" : "4500",
      "Contact" : "0704407239",
      "Device" : "Battery Malfunction",
      "Name" : "Omwanda",
      "Serial" : "HGJJI5445",
      "Served" : "Ritah",
      "Status" : "BALANCE"
    },
    "-MsZH138iBl03628oTpa" : {
      "AmountC" : "1500",
      "AmountP" : "1000",
      "Contact" : "0745234512",
      "Device" : "Charging system mulfunction",
      "Name" : "James ",
      "Serial" : "GFVHJK484",
      "Served" : "Ritah",
      "Status" : "Balance"
    },
    "-MsZHxwCHgmXk6cvwQEI" : {
      "AmountC" : "5000",
      "AmountP" : "3500",
      "Contact" : "0745234512",
      "Device" : "Laptop having Insufficient RAM",
      "Name" : "George",
      "Serial" : "GFVHJK488",
      "Served" : "Bonnie",
      "Status" : "Balance"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: strange. can you show me customers object

Comment: customers is a state. I have Setcustomers and customers. I am using the Object.keys because I set Setcustomers to take destractured snapshot value as an object

Comment: I have exported it

Comment: The property names are `AmountC`, `AmountP` but you are accessing `amountc` and `amountc`. Can you please try matching the case in your code? Also I cannot see any `cname` property in the data

Comment: Then I guess my problem was solved here. To me, I thought I am supposed to use the same keys when setting data. It Worked bro. You always solve my problems

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a typo.

Comment: @Dharmaraj are you good with MERn stack. please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903540/finding-user-with-admin-role-as-true

Comment: @Dharmaraj can you help with this>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71569229/how-to-write-data-firestore-database-with-document-as-user-uid-as-the-doc-id-fir